# Static code Analysis tool for SSIS

Tags: .net, ssis, static-code-analysis

Is there any static code analysis tool available for SSIS(Sql Server Integration Services) packages similar to Resharper, FxCop for dotnet applications. Which is the best tool available?

Comment: not to my knowledge but there is bids helper that adds some bits and pieces to bids.

Comment: Simply seconding T-I's comment that I'm not aware of a tool either. I'd happy give someone my money though for one

Comment: +1 for @TI, it looks good. Is there any other tool also available?

Comment: Haven't had a look at all the tools here - http://ssisctc.codeplex.com/ but good site for bookmarking anyway. I would go with bids helper as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check out BI xPress by Pragmatic Works. They have a feature they call "Best Practices Analyzer" which will review an SSIS package and report back possible bottle necks, etc. It's not exactly refactoring based on code smells, but it's close.

BI xPress also has a bunch of tools for code reuse, unit testing and real-time SSIS performance monitoring of deployed packages.

See: 
http://pragmaticworks.com/Products/BI-xPress